# Which email is used in Google OAuth 2.0 (Service Account) for Drive?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-openid, google-authentication, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to authentication with Google to use Google drive, but when I try to list files, none come back (and I know there are files in my Google Drive).

I'm using this code, and when I execute it, no files are listed.  Does it try to get files associated with my account blah@blah.com or 298741233858@developer.gserviceaccount.com?  Cause I have files in blah@blah.com but the 298741233858@developer.gserviceaccount.com was just created for the developer access.

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
import httplib2
from apiclient.discovery import build

email = 'blah@blah.com'
service_email = '298741233858@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

f = file('google-api-key', 'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(service_email, key, scope=scope)
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

def get_all_files(service):
  result = []
  page_token = None
  while True:
    param = {}
    if page_token:
      param['pageToken'] = page_token
    files = service.files().list(**param).execute()
    result.extend(files['items'])
    page_token = files.get('nextPageToken')
    if not page_token:
      break
  return result

files = get_all_files(drive_service)
print files
```

Comment: Did you setup the *service account email* as an alternative email address in your [*normale account*'s preferences](https://www.google.com/accounts/b/0/EditUserInfo)?

Comment: Hi Jan!  No, I used my normal email to setup the service account.  I can see on that page that it is associated with my normal email.  So basically, if I understand correctly... if I signed up for a regular google account using blah@blah.com, then add some files to drive, then I signup for an API account using blah@blah.com and get the email 298741233858@developer.gserviceaccount.com - I use 298741233858@developer.gserviceaccount.com for all API access and it should give me access to the data associated with blah@blah.com? (ie the files I uploaded?)

Comment: I'm not sure. I thought I had read somewhere, that you would have to setup the *service account email* as an alternative email for the accout you want to gain access to, but it could also be that my memory doesn't serve me right, as I can't find it anymore ;)

Comment: Any further information on the solution to this? Have the same issue for a normal Account. It works using a Domain with service accounts. But cannot get it to work for a normal user.